# QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found ''Android'' near line 1

Tags: jpa, jpql

How can I get the number of custom objects.
I have tried with the code below but I get error.

```
public Long countAndroid() {
    long androidCount = 0 ;
    Query query = entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT count(navig)  FROM testing t where t.navig=:'Android'");

    try {
           androidCount = (Long)query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();      // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return androidCount;

}
```

This is the error:

```
QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found ''Android'' near line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `t.navig=:'Android'` to

```
t.navig='Android'
```

if you want to use a parameter, you need `:navig`

```
t.navig = :navig
```